# regex question for the pattern exchange position

Tags: python, regex

```
exten => _407901XX,n,SipAddHeader(Diversion: <sip:${STN}@10.250.1.12>)
exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(SIP/ANDzF2BC/12503492,300,L(14400000))
exten => _407901XX,n,GotoIfTime(00:00-03:59,*,26,Dec,PST8PDT?close)
exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(SIP/Mit/${EXTEN:3},300,L(14400000))
exten => 6133523,n(ringgrp),Dial(Local/14846241@dfg_stores&Local/14845771@dfg_stores,15)
exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(SIP/Victoria/${EXTEN:3},300,L(14400000))
```

In a txt file with thousands of similar lines, I need to read the line from original file and I am looking to search for specific patterns and reformat them. As an example, in the above sample, I would replace the line `Dial(SIP/VictoriaSIPGateway/${EXTEN:3},300,L(14400000))` with `Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN:3},300,L(14400000)@VictoriaSIPGateway)`, transforming it according to these rules and write to the output txt file, if has the python will be perfect:

1. After `Dial(`, replace `SIP` with `PJSIP`.
2. All content from the second `/` to the last `)` is moved to just after the first `/`.
3. A `@` is placed after this content.
4. The content originally between the first two `/` is placed after the `@`.
5. The final `)` is placed last.
6. There are something else which which similar situation, but not start with `Dial(SIP`, so, also should not change anything at that line.
   I've been told there are special characters `$, {,},: (,)` in the second part, but am not sure what to do with this information.

Following these patterns, the transformed input becomes this output:

```
exten => _407901XX,n,SipAddHeader(Diversion: <sip:${STN}@10.250.1.12>)
exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(PJSIP/12503492,300,L(14400000)@ANDzF2BC)
exten => _407901XX,n,GotoIfTime(00:00-03:59,*,26,Dec,PST8PDT?close)
exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN:3},300,L(14400000)@Mit)
exten => 6133523,n(ringgrp),Dial(Local/14846241@dfg_stores&Local/14845771@dfg_stores,15)
exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN:3},300,L(14400000)@Victoria)
```

Answer (score 1):

for (1)

```
Dial\(SIP //-> replace with "Dial\(PJSIP"
```

for (2 - 5)

```
\/([^\/]*)(\/.*)\)(?:\n|$) //-> replace with "\2@\1\)"
```

JS Example:

```
const output = [
  "exten => _407901XX,n,SipAddHeader(Diversion: <sip:${STN}@10.250.1.12>)",  
  "exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(SIP/ANDzF2BC/12503603492,300,L(14400000))",
  "exten => _407901XX,n,GotoIfTime(00:00-03:59,*,26,Dec,PST8PDT?close)",
  "exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(SIP/Mit/${EXTEN:3},300,L(14400000))",
  "exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(SIP/Victoria/${EXTEN:3},300,L(14400000))"
]
.map(str => str.replace(/Dial\(SIP/g, "Dial\(PJSIP"))
.map(str => str.replace(/\/([^\/]+)(\/.*)\)(?:$|\n)/, "$2@$1\)"));

console.log(output);
/*
[
  "exten => _407901XX,n,SipAddHeader(Diversion: <sip:${STN}@10.250.1.12>)",
  "exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(PJSIP/12503603492,300,L(14400000)@ANDzF2BC)",
  "exten => _407901XX,n,GotoIfTime(00:00-03:59,*,26,Dec,PST8PDT?close)",
  "exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN:3},300,L(14400000)@Mit)",
  "exten => _407901XX,n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN:3},300,L(14400000)@Victoria)"
]
*/
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the quick response. Maybe I didn't ask the question clearly, the sample lines in the clear txt file, and need export to another txt file, and there is a similar line but not start with DIal(SIP, so, not touch those lines. It has a Python sample, which will be perfect.